# Using binary search to sort and array alphabeticall

Tags: java, recursion, binary

So i have an array list of unsorted words. I want to sort this list in alphabetical. My main problem is i'm getting StackOver flow. The other one is when i go around the Stack overflow it does not sort them aphabetically. (The binary search should not sort the whole array just give give the index at which the point should be added).

code:

```
public int binarySearch(ArrayList<String> a, String target) {
    return binarySearch(a, target, 0, a.size() - 1);
}

private int binarySearch(ArrayList<String> a, String target, int first,
        int last) {
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    if (first > last) {
        return first;
    }
    if (a.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (target.equals(a.get(mid))) {
        return mid;
    }
    if (a.get(mid).compareTo(target) > 0) {
        return binarySearch(a, target, mid - 1, last);
    }
    if (a.get(mid).compareTo(target) < 0) {
        return binarySearch(a, target, mid + 1, last);
    } else
        return mid;
}
```

Comment: Binary search isn't designed to sort an array. Can you describe how you're using it to sort?

Comment: As @templatetypedef says, this isn't a sort algorithm.  Binary search requires the array to **already** be sorted.

Comment: This is what i thought but as my teacher as assured me it can and has to be done this way. But its not suppose to sort the array in general its suppose to give an index.

Comment: So your teacher didn't say that: he said you can use it to search a sorted array, and give an index. So you've completely misunderstood the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
if (a.get(mid).compareTo(target) > 0) {
    return binarySearch(a, target, mid - 1, last);
}
```

If `target` is less than your pivot, you want to search the left half of the array, which is `first` to `mid-1`:

```
if (a.get(mid).compareTo(target) > 0) {
    return binarySearch(a, target, first, mid-1);
}
```

Instead, you're searching the right half plus the last element in the left half.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
private int binarySearch(ArrayList<String> a, String target, int first,
        int last) {
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    if (first > last) {
        return first;
    }
    if (a.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (target.equals(a.get(mid))) {
        return mid;
    } else {
        if (a.get(mid).compareTo(target) < 0) {
            return binarySearch(a, target, mid+1,last);
        }
        else{
            return binarySearch(a,target,first,mid-1);
        }
    }
}
```